# bootstrap dropdown doesn't work inside svg?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, dropdown, foreign-data-wrapper

```
... code omitted
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const margin = { top: 200, right: 55, bottom: 100, left: 180};
const width = 1250 - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


class Graphics extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

}


componentDidMount() {

    this.svg = d3.select(this.refs.container)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr( "transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    this.renderOptions();
}



componentDidUpdate(){

    this.renderOptions();
}


renderOptions(){

     const keys = ["cozy","luxury","loud","modern"];

     const container = d3.select(this.refs.container)
     .append('g')
         .attr('transform','translate(100,100)')
     .append('foreignObject')
         .attr('width','200px')
         .attr('height','200px')
     .append('xhtml:div')
         .attr('class','dropdown');

     container.append('xhtml:button')
         .attr('class','btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle')
         .attr('id','dropdownMenuButton')
         .attr('type','button')
         .attr('data-toggle','dropdown')
         .html('Select mood')
     .append('xhtml:span')
         .attr('class','caret')

     container.append('xhtml:div')
         .attr('class','dropdown-menu')
         .attr('aria-labelledby','dropdownMenuButton')
     .selectAll('option')
         .data(keys)
         .enter()
     .append('xhtml:a')
         .attr('class','dropdown-item')
         .html( d => d )

   }

render() {

    return (
        <main>

            <svg ref="container">
            </svg>

        </main>
    )
}
```

}

I am trying to append a bootstrap's dropdown menu inside svg, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work. The bootstrap's button shows up, but nothing happens when I click the button. Is it even possible to make it work in svg ? or should I just do it outside?

updated - apologize for unclear question. this.refs.container is referring to <svg ref="container"> which is react's dom node. svg itself doesn't have a problem since I see all contents in svg as well as the dropdown button. and you can also ignore transform as well. As from the example given by @Shashank shows it definitely work, but I wonder why it does not on my app despite the codes are the same. Here is additional code that are related to the problem.

Comment: It should work. Here's a fork: http://jsfiddle.net/fkmb3gL9/ Make sure you're including the BS files correctly. Also, personally, I'd NOT use this method but absolute position a div and use jQuery events.

Comment: @Shashank, your example does not reproduce the question's content faithfully. You are adding a `<svg>` element without sizing instruction and then leave out the `transform` attribute of `<g>`. If you would have added that, the button would have been moved outside the viewport and been invisible. But it is impossible to say if that is the real problem, since the question does not make clear what is selected with `this.refs.container`.

Comment: @ccprog Agreed that the question isn't fully clear. But looking at this part **The bootstrap's button shows up, but nothing happens when I click the button** and replying to OP's first question if it's even possible to make it work inside a SVG, I assumed the button being visible and so uploaded a fork showing that it does work in a SVG. Thanks btw.

Comment: apologize for unclear question. this.refs.container is referring to <svg ref="container"> which is react's dom node. svg itself doesn't have a problem since I see all contents in svg as well as the dropdown button. and you can also ignore transform as well. As from the example given by @Shashank shows it definitely work, but I wonder why it does not on my app despite the codes are the same. I edited my question with full code.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize again for give you confusion. I just found out that I didn't import bootstrap js files..